# Index based subset of SortedSet

Tags: java, collections, sortedset

I need to add objects from a `sourceList` to a collection that sorts the collection as we add objects to the collection. I am thinking of using [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

```
TreeSet bookSet
```

Based on certain conditions, I need to take subset of the `bookSet`. Subset will be first N elements. The value of `N` is known only after entire `bookSet` is prepared from another `sourceList`.

Is there anyway I can get the subset of bookSet using index N, Similar to arrayList.subList(0,N).

I can use [headSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#headSet%28E%29), but I need to know N+1 th element.

Comment: Use `headSet()`, then call `iterator()` on that and iterate over the next N elements.

Comment: You need to iterate through the set and get the first N elements. That would be linear time Or if you still have handle on sourceList, then get N+1 element from the sourceList and then call `headSet`.

Comment: Elements in sourceList are randomly ordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what your trying to achieve:

- You can use the `TreeSet.iterator()` and iterate `N` times.
- In Java 8 you can use `bookSet.stream().limit(N)`
- You can simply copy to an `new ArrayList(bookSet)` and then take a subList

Comment: Looks like 3rd option is what I am looking for :)

Comment: Option 3 would eliminate iterating by yourself, but under the hood, it does the same, if your collection is huge, better opt for Option 1, it would avoid copying the whole collection

Comment: Collection is not huge. Max elements can be 16.

Comment: If you really need option 3 then just sort your original list and take the sublist.